# Kafka: Source-Connector to Topic mapping is Flakey

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following Kafka connector configuration (below). I have created the "member" topic already (30 partitions). The problem is that I will install the connector and it will work; i.e.

```
curl -d "@mobiledb-member.json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT https://TTGSSQA0VRHAP81.ttgtpmg.net:8085/connectors/mobiledb-member-connector/config      

curl -s https://TTGSSQA0VRHAP81.ttgtpmg.net:8085/connectors/member-connector/topics
```

*returns:*

```
{"member-connector":{"topics":[member]}}
```

*the status call returns no errors:*

```
curl -s https://TTGSSQA0VRHAP81.ttgtpmg.net:8085/connectors/mobiledb-member-connector/status


{"name":"member-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"ttgssqa0vrhap81.***.net:8085"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"ttgssqa0vrhap81.***.net:8085"}],"type":"source"}
```

... but at other times, I will install a similar connector config and it will return no topics.

```
{"member-connector":{"topics":[]}}
```

Yet the status shows no errors and the Connector logs show no clues as to why this "connector to topic" mapping isn't working. Why aren't the logs helping out?

Connector configuration.

```
{
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "connection.url":"jdbc:sqlserver:****;",
    "connection.user":"***",
    "connection.password":"***",
    "transforms":"createKey",
    "table.poll.interval.ms":"120000",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "poll.interval.ms":"5000",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",

    "name":"member-connector",
    "tasks.max":"4",
    "query":"SELECT * FROM member_kafka_test",
    "table.types":"TABLE",
    "topic.prefix":"member",
    "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
    "transforms.createKey.fields":"member_id",
    "incrementing.column.name": "member_id",
    "timestamp.column.name" : "update_datetime"
}
```

Comment: The `/topics` endpoint is only a recent addition to the API. I suggest you create a JIRA for indicating bugs with it. Also, `topic.prefix` will start each topic with `member-`, **followed by the database schema name**, so that result isn't even the correct output for the topic that will be written to, and shouldn't be relied on (and the topic you created wont be used)

Comment: @OneCricketeer, but this isn't a problem with the /topics endpoint. The connector isn't linking with the topic. This is obvious by the topic not being populated. I only have access to the logs though Splunk, which aren't showing any errors. Is there a way to check and debug the connector through the CLI?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, from what I've gather from the documentation, the only way to specify a topic name is to write the name to the topic.prefix. I haven't see it just use the specified value as a prefix to the topic name. 
I have a custom query so:
"Prefix to prepend to table names to generate the name of the Apache Kafka® topic to publish data to, or in the case of a custom query, the full name of the topic to publish to."

Comment: If your custom query is just a `SELECT *` with no other filter, you shouldn't need a custom query. You can try using RegexRouter transform to have more control over the topic name, but still that is applied at runtime and the endpoint for the topics used by the connector probably won't accurately reflect what topic(s) are written to. If you list all the topics, which ones start with your prefix? Are any of those being populated?

Comment: @OneCricketeer. If I don't use a custom query, then what is the values of the "query" field?

Comment: It runs a `select *` by default, but adds where statements for your incrementing and timestamp columns. You can look at the database logs for more details